# Where I can buy "Maquia: When the Promised Flower Blooms" manga/light novel in English?

Tags: merchandise, maquia

I found [a link to Amazon Japan](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%95%E3%82%88%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%9D%E3%81%AB%E7%B4%84%E6%9D%9F%E3%81%AE%E8%8A%B1%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%96%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-1-%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F-%E4%BD%90%E8%97%A4-%E3%83%9F%E3%83%88/dp/4065133718) for さよならの朝に約束の花をかざろう (the Japanese title for *Maquia: When the Promised Flower Blooms*) manga, but I can't find the English edition/translation.

Where can I buy the English edition?

Comment: Note that the movie currently just has a manga adaptation, but not a light novel adaptation.

Comment: Sorry about that,  I didn't notice that earlier. Anyway, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunally you're out of luck. according to [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=150792) it has yet to be licensed for English

[image: Maquia: When the Promised Flower Blooms info from Manga Updates (25/3/2019)]

However it's currently only 1 volume in Japan and on-going having only came out last year so it's a new-ish series. so it's still possible it could come out

Comment: Like, how much chapter would be expected finish?

Comment: @GilangRizqi I don't think it's possible for us to answer that. Even if it has finished, there's also no certainty that it will be localized to English/other languages either.